# perl s/this/that/r ==> "Bareword found where operator expected"

Tags: perl, bareword

[Perl docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) recommend this:

```
$foo = $bar =~ s/this/that/r;
```

However, I get this error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected near
    "s/this/that/r" (#1)
```

This is specific to the `r` modifier, without it the code works.
However, I do not want to modify `$bar`.
I can, of course, replace

```
my $foo = $bar =~ s/this/that/r;
```

with

```
my $foo = $bar;
$foo =~ s/this/that/;
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Is this running on Perl 5.14… ? (Make sure you have a `require v5.14;` in your header…)

Comment: Edit: apparently `use v5.13.2` is the minimum level for `s///r`.

Comment: What have we learned here? We have learned that we should read the docs *that came with* out perl distribution rather than reading docs from "somewhere on the web".  :-)

Comment: @BRPocock, 5.13.x are a dev releases. No reason to mention those.

Comment: @tadmc, I thought the lesson was: Upgrading to the latest Perl has benefits :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As ruakh wrote, `/r` is new in perl 5.14. However you can do this in previous versions of perl:

```
(my $foo = $bar) =~ s/this/that/;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no better solution, no (though I usually write it on one line, since the `s///` is essentially serving as part of the initialization process:

```
my $foo = $bar; $foo =~ s/this/that/;
```

By the way, the reason for your error-message is almost certainly that you're running a version of Perl that doesn't support the `/r` flag. That flag was added quite recently, in Perl 5.14. You might find it easier to develop using the documentation for your own version; for example, http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.4/perlop.html if you're on Perl 5.12.4.

Answer (score -1):

For completeness.
If you are stuck with an older version of `perl`.
And really want to use the `s///` command without resorting to using a temporary variable.
Here is one way:

```
perl -E 'say map { s/_iter\d+\s*$//; $_ } $ENV{PWD}'
```

Basically use map to transform a copy of the string and return the final output.
Instead of what `s///` does - of returning the count of substitutions.